# Gitolite unable to disable access to directory

Tags: git

I am using gitolite v3.5.2-3-g2515992 on git 1.7.1 with smart-http and a script to get users groups in Active Directory.

I want to denied access to a directory fof a particular group.
here is my config file

```
repo WebSrc
    R       =   @GP_Developpers_1
    RW+     =   @GP_Developpers_2
    -       VREF/NAME/private/        = @GP_Developpers_2
```

All is perfect (`GP_Developpers_1` is read only and `GP_Developpers_2` can read and write) except that gitolite does'nt apply `VREF` rule. `GP_Developpers_2` can push updates on file private/test.txt.

Can you tell me what is missed

Thanks fo your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html) your configuration looks good.

Before continuing with anything else I would update to a newer git version - 1.7.1 is really old and there were plenty of bugfixes. I bet this solves your problems.

Comment: I am using the Centos 6 package. Of course it is not the last version of git, but as Gitolite is a layer above git not sure that could help. Never mind it should be tried